# Calling a function pointer in C without *

Tags: c, function-pointers

I need to understand why we can call a pointer to a function in C without * as if we are calling a regular function (which may confuse a reader to the program since he may search for a function with this name and would not find it)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int , int);

int main(void){

    int a, b, total;
    int (*ptr_sum)(int x, int y)=sum;

    printf("Enter a:");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("Enter b:");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    total=(*ptr_sum)(a, b);  //************line 1
    total=ptr_sum(a, b);     //************line 2
    printf("The total = %d\n", total);

    return(0);
}

int sum(int m, int n) {
    return m+n;
}
```

On line 1 we called the function pointer using the `*` operator. On line 2 we called it once again but without `*`, just as if it were a regular function.

Why? Why both are the same?

Comment: Syntactic sugar; that's just the way C is. Do you want me to dig up a spec reference?

Comment: Also notice how in this line `int (*ptr_sum)(int x, int y)=sum;` the function name got converted to a pointer without `&`.